# Como formatear una fecha de laravel y mostrarla en componente Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo esta consulta en mi modelo:

```
public static function traerVacantes(){
$vacantes = Vacante::join("empresas", "vacantes.empresa_id", "=", "empresas.id")
             ->join("cargos", "vacantes.cargo_id", "=", "cargos.id")
             ->join("sucursales", "vacantes.sucursal_id", "=", "sucursales.id")
             ->join("comunas", "sucursales.comuna_id", "=", "comunas.id")
             ->join("regiones", "comunas.region_id", "=", "regiones.id")
             ->select("vacantes.descripcion as descripcion", "vacantes.created_at as fecha_creado", 
                    "vacantes.fecha_fin as fecha_fin", "vacantes.estado as estado", "vacantes.codigo as codigo", 
                    "empresas.nombre as empresa", "cargos.nombre as cargo", "sucursales.direccion as sucursal", 
                    "comunas.nombre as comuna", "regiones.nombre as region");

  return $vacantes;

}
```

tengo el siguiente resultado en el console.log()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que hago con estos datos en mostrarlos en una lista compuesta por elementos `<card>` y se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es formatear la fecha del created_at que muestro en la parte superior derecha de la `<card>` ... necesito que se vea así d-m-Y.

estos son los protected de mi modelo Vacante:

```
protected $table = "vacantes";

protected $fillable = [

   'id', 'empresa_id', 'sucursal_id', 'cargo_id', 'descripcion', 'codigo', 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin', 'estado', 'created_at'
];
```

les agradezco, muchos gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué no esta pregunta ya fue hecha y te la respondió @Shaz? indicándote como darle el formato deseado

Comment: @αλρθα esta es un poco distinta.

Comment: Ahora si el problema esta con algo relacionado a VueJS, entonces edita e indica dicho inconveniente... pues como esta redactada ahorita es casi un clon de la que ya publicaste antes

Comment: Esta pregunta es un problema distinto a la otra que citan, puesto que se está solicitando como «exportar» una fecha de Laravel para ser utilizada en Vue. La otra pregunta era cómo cambiar el formato de la fecha, pero estando en Laravel.

Comment: amigos les agradezco y me disculpan si he cometido un error en formular la pregunta, pero les cuento que lo he solucionado utilizando la librería moment en vue con la siguiente función:        since: function(d){
            return moment(d).fromNow();
        },

Comment: No es necesario usar moment para eso, pero bueno...